# Javascript string

Tags: javascript, string

I have got a method which finds a required value in an array.

```
let result = arrayStart.find(obj => obj.data === `${constValue1}/${constValue2}/${constValue3}`)
```

Will JavaScript create each time a new string in each iteration, e.g.

```
`${constValue1}/${constValue2}/${constValue3}`
```

or will it create only once?

Comment: The former. But the value of that string seems to be the same (if nothing mutates `constValue1/2/3` between the cycles.

Comment: That somewhat depends on the internals of the specific Javascript engine. Some engines *might* be clever enough to optimise this internally. However, it probably won't do so unless you call this particular piece of code quite often.

Comment: If you're worried about that, just move it out:

 const compareTo = `${constValue1}/${constValue2}/${constValue3}`;
 let result = arrayStart.find(obj => obj.data === compareTo)

Answer (score 0):

The string will be created each time, think of find as a loop that will loop through each element in an array and on each iteration you are constructing a string. I wouldn't worry too much about it as its not being assigned to any variable you are just using it for equality but if you want to make it better i would create a variable outside the callback passed to find and assign it there and use that variable for equality.

such as:

```
const newString = `${constValue1}/${constValue2}/${constValue3}`;
let result = arrayStart.find(obj => obj.data === newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not a compiled language, it is interpreted as it runs. This means that there is no sure-fire way for the engine to know what `constValue`'s are in advance, even if they are declared `const`. This means that in order to know what the final value of the string is, the interpreter has to re-compute it every time.

Normally I would write such code like this:

```
const searchTerm = `${constValue1}/${constValue2}/${constValue3}`;
let result = arrayStart.find(obj => obj.data === searchTerm);
```

However, keep in mind that in terms of performance, this requires scope resolution (the engine needs to find where the value `searchTerm` is defined), so that takes a tiny bit of time as well.

Also, some smarter code processors (i.e. minimizers) might be able to see that this value never changes and extract it in the same manner, but I would not count on that.